# Socket Reset Exception - Java

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, stack-trace, packet

I am trying to send a `ByteBuffer` array over a socket on the port 25565 on the address "localhost". But for some reason, Java is throwing a connection reset exception when doing `input.read()`. Could someone please tell me whats going on?

Sender:

```
private static Socket socket;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    socket = new Socket("localhost", 25565);
    String Password = "1234";
    ByteBuffer Buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1 + Password.getBytes().length);
    Buffer.put((byte) 0x00);
    Buffer.putShort((short) Password.getBytes().length);
    Buffer.put(Password.getBytes());
    DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    output.write(Buffer.array());
}

public static void sendBytes(byte[] myByteArray) throws IOException {
    DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    output.write("LOL".getBytes());
    output.flush();
}
```

Receiver:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        ServerSocket ServerSocket = new ServerSocket(25565);
        System.out.println("Waiting for connection...");
        Socket socket = ServerSocket.accept();
        DataInputStream Input = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
        System.out.println(Input.read());
        ServerSocket.close();
        socket.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if(e instanceof SocketTimeoutException) {
            System.out.println("THE SOCKET TIMED OUT!");
        }
        else {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Stack trace:

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:189)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:83)
at net.networking.Receiver.main(Receiver.java:17)
```

NOTE: Yes, I do know that just using `input.read()` will not get the whole `ByteBuffer` array I'm trying to send. But right now I just want to read the first byte and print it out to the console.

Answer (score 1):

1. You're not closing the connection in the sender, so it gets reset when the process exits.

   ```
   private static Socket socket;

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
       socket = new Socket("localhost", 25565);
       String Password = "1234";
       sendBytes(Password.getBytes());
       output.close();
   }

   public static void sendBytes(byte[] myByteArray) throws IOException {
       ByteBuffer Buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(3 + myByteArray.length);
       Buffer.put((byte) 0x00);
       Buffer.putShort((short) myByteArray.length);
       Buffer.put(myByteArray);
       DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
       output.write(Buffer.array());
       output.flush();
   }
   ```
2. You're only reading one byte and then closing the connection. You need to read the entire transmission. If you close a socket with unread data still pending, the connection is reset.  Also, if you want to handle exceptions separately, *catch* them separately. Don't use `instanceof`.

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       try {
           ServerSocket ServerSocket = new ServerSocket(25565);
           System.out.println("Waiting for connection...");
           Socket socket = ServerSocket.accept();
           DataInputStream Input = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
           byte b = Input.readByte();
           short dataLen = Input.readShort();
           byte[] data = new byte[dataLen];
           Input.readFully(data);
           // use data as needed...
           System.out.println("Data received");
           Input.close();
           ServerSocket.close();
       } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
           System.out.println("THE SOCKET TIMED OUT!");
       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Still doesnt work, tried what you said. Could you send me the exact code fix you were proposing? I just want to make sure I put what you mean.